# how to use the properrty

Tags: soapui

Can anyone assist me to solve this query in the below mentioned scenario…?
first of all i’ve created a testsuite for every individual web service, for handling all types of its respective testcases like, request succeeded, internal server error bla bla.
My app is login based. and on successful login, login API returns session id and some other values in the response.
ive another suite which fetches the latest studies from the server for that sessionid which is generated as a response in testsuite 1. Can you help me to use this property (sessionid ) as a param while invoking the other APIs (for instance, getlateststudies) being the part of other testsuites….in this case i want to fetch the latest studies for that sessionid.
As you know that values for such params, like, sessionid is system generated. so can the wild character (*) be sued in this case.
Im sort of new to SOAPUI , have already taken help from soap UI online help links but the entire help is related to using the property as a param in the same testsuite and NOT across the various testsuites.
Please elaborate all the steps if you know how to proceed ahead.
for more clarity , let me the define the hierarchy which i’ve structured in my workspace.
Userlogin /*testsuite 1, represents the login API*/
Request succeeded /*testcase name , represents a scenario*/
teststep1
method1-request1
/*This testcases returns system generated sessionid as a value upon invoking*/
getlateststudies /*test suite 2, represents the API to fetch the latest studies from server for
that sessionid */
Request succeeded /*testcase name , represents a scenario*/
teststep1
method1-request1
Do i need to use any groovy script for it ?
I’ve already tried using property transefer feature of soap UI within the same testsuite but
tell me some suitable solution to use it across the test suites of the same project.

---

@ Steve, Thanks for ur reply. i actually followed the steps mentioned in the 2nd most link  provided by you as per my last conversation with you, the sessionid param is a server generated id and it couldn't be hard coded.Just want to  discuss with you what i did!i defined a property at the project level sessionid and imported its value from an external source, say .txt file and in which ive saved the value of sessionid with a wild character , i-e, *. keeping in view the fact that it will pick the server generated sessionid and i really didn't want to pass the hard-coded value. i later made use of property transfer feature to select the source and target properties names and their values. want to double-check with you  is my approach correct , if not , then please provide your valuable comments! or if passing the wild card character is not correct for the server generated id , then what should be the other possible option to represent this ?

Comment: Sorry for late reply.  That sounds like it would work.  Is there anywhere else you could pull the session id from?  Another soap request?  Could you grab it from a back end system(using a jdbc step)?

Answer (score 2):

You are close, it sounds like you are just using the wrong property type.  soapUI has several levels.

- Global- available globally
- Project- available across the project
- TestSuite- available across the suite
- TestCase- available in the testcase

You need to use a property transfer to a project level property, so add a custom property at the project level and then use property transfer to that property you created.  Use xpath to pull the piece of data you need.  Finally, you need to use that project property in your new request ${#Project#PropertyName}

All the tools to put this together are available from the soapUI website.

http://www.soapui.org/Functional-Testing/xpath-and-xquery-assertions.html#1-the-xpath-match-assertion

http://www.soapui.org/Functional-Testing/working-with-properties.html

http://www.soapui.org/Functional-Testing/transferring-property-values.html